# change new line encoding from \r\n to \n in php

Tags: php, newline, twilio-api

I am using Twillio API, to send WhatsApp Messages.

But the Message template needs to be pre-approved in order to send a message.

But It always fails when there are multiple lines of the message.

The reason is they match the new line as \n, as the template is registered with a Unix-style line feed in their system, but My template is sending `\r\n` encoding for the new line which is window based.

How can I change newline encoding from `\r\n` to `\n` in my system?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the code you use

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = str_replace("\r\n","\n", $windowStr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have tried this before. but your answer guided me to think differently. so definitely upVote... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue using the below code.

```
$windows_encoded_data = urlencode($data);

$unix_encoded = str_replace("%0D%0A","%0A",$windows_encoded_data);

$final_data = urldecode($unix_encoded);
```